# Want to learn real analysis.

Tags: real-analysis, book-recommendation

I want to learn real analysis nicely. I like Walter rudin real analysis but I have time constraints too. I have red analysis earlier also but I want to fix myself to almost two books for now.. Since in the time period of two to three months maximum it's not possible to read Walter rudin properly. So I thought let me take two books one Walter rudin for motivation and it's elegance and other which would be little easy so that I can cover a good amount of Syallabus as well. So please suggest me a book which I can use with Walter rudin which will give me more details and will be less time taking to go through. 
 I want to know that whether I should go for a calculus book like by Micheal spivak or Adrian banner or any other or understanding analysis by Stephan Abbot ? 
 I know pre calculus. I want to learn those calculus concepts now with more rigour so that It will help me understand rudin more better way.

Comment: Take [this one](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781461462705).

Comment: There is no Royal Road. Rudin is an amazing text, but I find it exceedingly terse. I like pictures. I liked Marsden's "Real Analysis" as an early introduction.

Comment: Apostol's calculus and analysis are other possible choices. I love those texts. Also Terry Tao's analysis.

Comment: Thanks  for your response

Comment: It's true you can't replace Rudin , if you want to learn mathematical  Analysis .But you can try "Introduction to Real analysis" by Bartle and Sherbert if you have time constraints .

Comment: Yaa really. I have that book as well. For calculus will you please suggest a good one? There are so many great text what to choose?  I need some guidance. I was thinking of having one Walter rudin and other a book which help me to fill the gaps. Because I do not want to refer so many texts.